# NodeJS: Get image as response from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My client has stored a large number of images on S3. We need to get these images back as response. Here is the code I've written:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: "AccessKey",
        secretAccessKey: "SecretAccessKey"
    });
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    s3.getObject({ Bucket: "BucketName", Key: "ImageURL" },
        function(error, data) {
            if (error != null) {
                var _length = data.Body.length;
                //Execution freezes here. Don't get any response.
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
                    'Content-Length': _length
                });
                res.end(new Buffer(data.Body, 'binary'));
                } 
        }
    );
```

How can we get the image in response?

Comment: `//Execution freezes here.`  You don't have an `else` block.  And why exactly do you treat `if (error != null)` as... success?  Don't you have the logic backwards?

Answer (score 0):

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "AccessKey",
    secretAccessKey: "SecretAccessKey"
});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.getObject({ Bucket: "BucketName", Key: "ETag.jpeg" },
    function(error, data) {
        if (error != null) {
            alert("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
        } else {
            alert("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");                    
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: this didn't work either. I suppose we need to give the URL for this to work. Is there any example that has the code to send image as response? I am updating my question.